# Paint effect onmouseover (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dhtml

I'm looking at [this example](http://jsbin.com/akIyecO/17/edit).

I'm wondering if it would be possible to track the mouse cursor, so that once you mouse over part of the image it stays color? Sort of like you're painting or coloring it in. Is there a specific plug-in I should be looking for or how could I accomplish that?

Comment: You could modify the code I wrote a few years ago to do something similar (http://www.catchmyfame.com/2011/06/28/a-jquery-canvas-scratch-off/). Just use one grayscale image and one color image.

Comment: @j08691 Thank you. Could you reply with the source code of your example and I'll accept the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the jQuery:

```
/*
 * jQuery + Canvas Scratch Off
 * @author admin@catchmyfame.com - http://www.catchmyfame.com
 * @version 1.0
 * @date June 28, 2011
 * @copyright (c) 2011 admin@catchmyfame.com (www.catchmyfame.com)
 * @license CC Attribution-NoDerivs 3.0 Unported - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/
 */
var topImage = new Image();
var bottomImage = new Image();
var coinImage = new Image();
bottomImage.src = "bottom-300.jpg";
coinImage.src = "circle.png";   

function init()
{
    var isMouseDown = false;
    var canvasWidth = $('#canvas').width();
    var canvasHeight = $('#canvas').height();
    $('body').append('<canvas id="overlay" width="'+canvasWidth+'" height="'+canvasHeight+'" />'); // Create the coin overlay canvas
    var overlayctx = $('canvas')[1].getContext('2d');
    overlayctx.drawImage(coinImage, 0,0);


    function scratchOff(x, y)
    {
        mainctx.save();
        mainctx.beginPath();
        mainctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false); // we don't fill or stroke the arc intentionally
        mainctx.clip();
        mainctx.drawImage(bottomImage, 0, 0);
        mainctx.restore();
    }

    $('#overlay').mousedown(function(e){
            isMouseDown = true;
            var relX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var relY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
            scratchOff(relX, relY, true);
    });
    $('#overlay').mousemove(function(e){
        var relX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var relY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        overlayctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
        overlayctx.drawImage(coinImage, relX-radius, relY-radius);
        if (isMouseDown) scratchOff(relX, relY, false);
    });
    $('#overlay').mouseup(function(e){
        isMouseDown = false;
    });

    var mainctx = $('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
    var radius = 15;
    topImage.onload = function(){
        mainctx.drawImage(topImage, 0, 0);
    };
    topImage.src = "top-300.jpg";
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="225"></canvas>
```